# Download dynamic generated pdf from dynamic url which is being viewed in webbrowser control in adobe viewer in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, download, webbrowser-control

I am developing a windows application in vb.net in which i have a url which first ask me to login on the website and then display a view pdf link. As i make it click it again redirect to another page where instead of asking for download pdf it opens it in my web browser control. Now i want to save that opened pdf on my specified path. I have googled a lot but didn't find any solution for the same. I even found some related posts but none of them have my answer. Here my pdf url doesnt contains any file name like '.pdf'. Url contains some token values. To open this url it requires login on the website. I am trying to download pdf file for many days. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you have to push your file using http headers
Unique HTTP Headers Returned 
because these headers are the only thing controlling how your browser handles the file.
Save As Mode (askapache_pdf=s)

Content-Disposition: attachment
Content-Type: application/pdf
for more info goto http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/pdf-cookies-headers-rewrites.html#Unique_HTTP_Headers_Returned

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have checked this out, but not getting this. This is in PHP. Can u add some code snippet in .net?

Answer (score 0):

This does not have anything to do with server side scripting language its same that you have to add a response in your header of http request. But anyway in ASP you should try something like below
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=somefile.ext")